# How do I get a stable IPv6 address in 16.04?

Tags: 16.04, ipv6

I have a domain name that points toward my home server. Under every Ubuntu release up through Wily, by default I had a stable EIU-64 address that I could use for my AAAA record. However, after installing Xenial, I don't seem to get a stable address by default.

```
joejoe@myserver:~$ ip address
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: enp2s0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 00:24:1d:d2:e3:f4 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.0.101/24 brd 192.168.0.255 scope global enp2s0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 2601:280:3068:2945:74ed:b303:6474:6e29/64 scope global temporary dynamic
       valid_lft 6965sec preferred_lft 3363sec
    inet6 2601:280:3068:2945:ac34:ea15:4340:29a4/64 scope global temporary deprecated dynamic
       valid_lft 6965sec preferred_lft 0sec
    inet6 2601:280:3068:2945:bdfd:6253:b07e:1308/64 scope global mngtmpaddr noprefixroute dynamic
       valid_lft 6965sec preferred_lft 6965sec
    inet6 fe80::dc3e:6127:bd4e:18b/64 scope link
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

As you can see, all of the `inet6` addresses with `scope global` have limited lifetimes. Is there a way to get my EIU-64 address back, or is there some other way to get a stable address that I can use in a domain name record?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I just figured this out. For each connection in `/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/`, you need to set the following property:

```
[ipv6]
addr-gen-mode=eui64
```

NetworkManager in 16.04 appears to set a default of `stable-privacy` for the `addr-gen-mode` setting.

Answer (score 7):

The other answers here are a bit incomplete: changing NetworkManager configs doesn't help if you don't *have* one (which is actually the problem, see below), and disabling IPv6 privacy extensions is actually somewhat unrelated (again if your supposedly-stable IPv6 address changes on each boot, removing the extra privacy addresses doesn't help).

As detailed in [this thread](http://www.gossamer-threads.com/lists/nsp/ipv6/57973), a default, new install of 16.04 has a slight oversight if you are using a wired connection. NetworkManager automatically generates an "ephemeral" configuration, which works great but is, well, ephemeral. This means that the GUID used to hash into a supposedly-consistent IPv6 address isn't stored, and so you get a new one each boot. Just going into NetworkManager, pressing "edit" on the wired connection, and saving it with no changes will generate an actual NM config, with a saved GUID, and so you'll get the same IPv6 address each boot.

This address is an RFC7217 address (a crypto hash of the GUID, your prefix, etc etc) -- so although it's stable each boot, it isn't the sort that includes your MAC address into the address directly. If you want one of those EUI64 addresses, [this other answer on this question](https://askubuntu.com/a/779047) details how to change that.

Answer (score 6):

Ubuntu 16.04 and previous releases have always defaulted to the EIU-64 for me, so for servers I have to disable it.  I'm happy to use the privacy address on my desktop.

So you need something like:

```
    sysctl -w net.ipv6.conf.all.use_tempaddr=0
    sysctl -w net.ipv6.conf.default.use_tempaddr=0
    sysctl -w net.ipv6.conf.default.use_tempaddr=0
    sysctl -w net.ipv6.conf.<devname>.use_tempaddr=0
```

Then ifdown/ifup.  The result for me, note the MAC/IPv6 relationship:

```
$ ifconfig enp3s0 | egrep 'HWaddr|Global'
enp3s0    Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 74:d0:2b:90:8b:90  
          inet6 addr: 2501:300:d008:61c8:76d0:2bff:fe90:8b90/64 Scope:Global
```

You can name specific interfaces if you need it enabled on some interfaces not others.  You can see the list with:

```
$ sysctl -a | grep tempaddr
```

I don't recommend Network manager for production services.  For instance it doesn't it does't play well others, like /etc/sysctl.conf for instance.  If you want to do that you willl need an entry in /etc/networking/interfaces for a static address or an automatically configured one.  I'm just using:

```
auto enp3s0 
iface enp3s0 inet dhcp
iface enp3s0 inet6 auto
pre-up modprobe ipv6
```

Adjust to taste of course.

Comment: Sorry for taking to long to accept, but I'm having trouble with your answer. Beyond your suggestion of using `sysctl -w`, I've tried writing `net.ipv6.conf.all.use_tempaddr = 0, net.ipv6.conf.default.use_tempaddr = 0` to `/etc/sysctl.d/10-ipv6-privacy.conf` and restarting, and the Network Manager GUI indicates that privacy extensions are disabled, but I still end up with IPv6 addresses that are temporary and not related to my MAC address.

Comment: Well tinkering with sysctl is incompatible with the network manager.  Do you have something like this in /etc/network/interfaces:  
`auto enp3s0 \n
iface enp3s0 inet dhcp \n
iface enp3s0 inet6 auto \n
pre-up modprobe ipv6 \n
`
That should disable network manager for that interface.  But the places it can be are /etc/sysctl.conf or something like /etc/sysctl.d/10-ipv6-privacy.conf.  If you want to fix it with networkmanager there should be a per interface file under /etc/NetworkManager/system_connections and you can put a ip6-privacy=0 under [ipv6]

Comment: Hrm, thanks for the tip about the NetworkManager config files, but `ip6-privacy=0` is already present there. Seems like possibly a NetworkManager bug.

I'll switch to `ifup/down` as you suggest and see what that does.

Comment: This [Launchpad bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/network-manager/+bug/998223) says NM should now be reading from the `sysctl` settings but there are reports near the end that it is not fixed.

Comment: Confirmed: switching to `ifup/down` and `sysctl` instead of Network Manager can disable IPv6 privacy extensions.